# NumberFormatException: null in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, jdbc

I have a form in which user creates an Event with information (e.g. Event Id, event name. event location ...)

The event information is then stored in database ( Using jsp for form, java beans getter and setter, jdbc sql).

I want to retrieve all the event information and display it onto another jsp page but i am getting numberformatexception null error.

I have ran a test java file which gets all the events information correctly with no error, however when I try to display it onto the jsp page inside a table, i get errors.

When i try to put the following url in the address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/Assignment/addEvent?action=list
```

i get number format except null error.

The WebServlet url pattern is "/addEvent".

The following are my related code.

Code for EventController Servlet

```
    String action = request.getParameter("action");



          if ("list".equalsIgnoreCase(action)) {
        // call the query db to get retrieve for all customer 
        init();
        ArrayList events = db.queryEvents();
        // set the result into the attribute

        request.setAttribute("events", events);
        // redirect the result to the listCustomers.jsp
        RequestDispatcher rd;
        rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/AllEventsDisplay.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Creating event failed!!");
    }
```

AllEventsDisplay.jsp page

```
<%
                 ArrayList<EventBean> events = (ArrayList<EventBean> )request.getAttribute("events");
                out.println("<h1>Events</h1>");



                out.println("<table border='1'>");
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<th>Event ID</th>  <th> Event Name</th><th> Event Location</th><th> Event Venue</th ><th> Event Date</th ><th> Event Helpers</th ><th> Helper Type</th >");
                out.println("</tr>");
  // loop through the customer array to display each customer record
                for (int i = 0; i < events.size(); i++) {
                    EventBean c = events.get(i);
                    out.println("<tr>");

                    out.println("<td>" + c.getEventID() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getEventname() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getLocation() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getVenue() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getDate() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getNumofhelper() + "</td>");
                    out.println("<td>" + c.getHelpertype() + "</td>");


                    out.println("</tr>");

                }
                out.println("</table>");
    %>
```

The EventDB method for getting the event information

```
        public ArrayList queryEvents() {
    Connection cnnct = null;
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = null;
    EventBean cb = null;
    ArrayList ca = new ArrayList();
    try {
        cnnct = getConnection();
        String preQueryStatement = "SELECT * FROM EventInfo";
        pStmnt = cnnct.prepareStatement(preQueryStatement);
        ResultSet rs = null;
        rs = pStmnt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            cb = new EventBean();
            cb.setEventID(rs.getString(1));
            cb.setEventname(rs.getString(2));
            cb.setLocation(rs.getString(3));
            cb.setVenue(rs.getString(4));
            cb.setDate(rs.getString(5));
            cb.setNumofhelper(rs.getInt(6));
            cb.setHelpertype(rs.getString(7));
            ca.add(cb);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            ex = ex.getNextException();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        while (ex != null) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    return ca;

   }
```

**Please note that NumofHelper is an integer.**

**The error stacktrace**

```
WARNING:StandardWrapperValve[EventController]: Servlet.service() for servlet 
                         EventController threw exception

java.lang.NumberFormatExcept ion: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
at ict.servlet.EventController.processRequest(EventController.java:65)
at ict.servlet.EventController.doGet(EventController.java:45)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   visiting unvisited references
INFO:   Loading application [Assignment] at [/Assignment]
INFO:   Assignment was successfully deployed in 322 milliseconds.

Comment: Are you sure that the table `EventInfo` in the DB doesn't have a record with `null` ? please post the full stacktrace.

Comment: In my sql create table part, i have specified each value to be NOT NULL, i've checked the database as well, theres no record with null value.

Comment: I am using netbeans with glassfish 4.0, how do i show the full stacktrace?

Comment: I understand that it's not null, is it (the field in the DB) also defined as `INT` ? did you try to print what you get from `rs.getInt(6)` ? I can't really help you with the stacktrace - try to figure it out cause you'll need it if you intend to continue and developing with Netbeans/Glassfish

Comment: Which line is EventController.java:65 ?

Comment: It is this one, i didnt include it in the question sorry.

Comment: int NumberofHelper = Integer.parseInt(EventHelpers);

Comment: are there any other ways to display the event information from the database onto jsp

Comment: Edit your question to include the full source of your EventController class.  It looks to me as if the error is in there, and if so, you are making it very difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In EventController.java the EventHelpers value is a null value. You are not check that value is null or not, you are try to parse the "null" value. So it gives NullPointerException.

```
 int NumberofHelper = 0;
 if(EventHelpers != null){
    NumberofHelper  = Integer.parseInt(EventHelpers);
}
```

Try this one